# Filter array with nested objects Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular5

I'm trying to filter a list with many objects with the following structure:

```
{  
"element1":{  
  "code":"12345",
  "location":"Location"
},
"users":[  
  {  
     "id":1,
     "name":"Name 1",
     "surname":"Surname 1",
  },
  {  
     "id":2,
     "name":"Name 2",
     "surname":"Surname 2",
  }
 ]
}
```

Right now I am filtering it by the first element like this:

```
filterList(value) {

    if (value&& value.trim() != '') {
        myList = myList .filter((item) => {
            return (item.element1.location.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1);
        })
    }
}
```

I've been trying to adapt this to filter them by the users attribute which is a list of objects and inside that by the surname what do I have to change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter by users' surname by replacing filter condition as below. This will return parent object which have one that matches the given surname.

```
return (item.users.some(i => i.surname.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1));
```

If you want the list of users then your filter would be like as below.

```
var usersList = [];
myList.forEach(i => Array.prototype.push.apply(usersList, i.users));
usersList = usersList.filter(i => i.surname.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1);
```

Comment: I guess u meant return (item.users.some(i => i.surname.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1));
This is returning all the users of the object that has one that matches the given surname, I need only the user with that surname. Not sure if the filter is still not correct or if it is and I have to aproach this differently.

Comment: Yes. It was my bad. Just updated answer. Now in next snippet it will return list of users which have matching surname.